# Linux tap interface not forwarding ip fragmentations

Tags: linux, networking

I have 4 tap interfaces, tap0 and tap1 is connected and so is tap2 and tap3

```
vde_switch -d -tap tap0 -tap tap1 click
vde_switch -d -tap tap2 -tap tap3 --sock /run/vde.ctl/ctl2
```

I then assigned ip for tap1 and tap2

```
ip addr add 1.1.1.1/24 dev tap1
ip addr add 1.2.1.1/24 dev tap2
```

From raw socket application, I sent a udp packet from tap0 with source ip 1.1.1.3 and destination ip 1.2.1.3 and it arrived at tap3 (according to wireshark).

The problem is, if I send fragmented ip/udp packet, Linux doesn't forward it to tap3.

I checked the fragmented ip packet (first segment), its checksum and destination mac addr are all right.  The funny thing is, if I remove the "more fragment" bit in ip header (ip checksum will change), then it got forwarded.

By the way, I am using Linux 3.19.0-65 on 64bit laptop.

Any idea why?   Thanks a lot!

**EDIT1**

Here is the output of `ip route list`

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
1.1.1.0/24 dev tap1  proto kernel  scope link  src 1.1.1.1 
1.2.1.0/24 dev tap2  proto kernel  scope link  src 1.2.1.1 
10.0.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.3  metric 9 
172.16.83.0/24 dev vmnet1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.83.1 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 
192.168.181.0/24 dev vmnet8  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.181.1
```

**Edit2**

Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kk6jmow0ygo4xwp/ipFrag.pcap) to the pcap of the IP fragment packet, captured on tap0 interface.

Comment: could you share the output for 'ip route list'

Comment: Added the output of the command. Thx.

Comment: Sorry, should have asked earlier, I think it will help to analyse if you could please also share the output of tcpdump or wireshark while running your test.

Comment: Thanks @SiddharthTyagi for asking, it's posted there.

Comment: To clarify: Do you mean that the single part of the fragmented packet is not forwarded until you sent the remainder, or do you mean that any fragmented packets aren't forwarded at all?

Comment: @Phillip it appears that fragmented ip packet is not forwarded at all. If I change the more bit (need to adjust ip header checksum), it will pass through.

Comment: @packetie That's not quite what I meant. I've been thinking that the kernel might intentionally not forward the packet before it's complete. That would actually make sense, because the MTU towards the next hop might be sufficiently large to hold the whole packet. So what happens if after the packet from your pcap you send a second packet which is the continuation of the first one and does not have the MF bit set?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @Phillip, I set up the same environment (tap and vde_switch) on another Ubuntu and it worked fine.  I suspect it's some kind of configuration.